# How to convert a 2d-numpy array to diagonal matrix with padded 0?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm not sure how to go about this,
example:

```
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

convert it to this:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 3]])
```

`np.diag` only works on 1d array to diagonal matrix.
I can get it with iterative approach with for loop and slices, but I feel there might be a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) with some self generated indices:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]])

h, w = arr.shape
w_out = h + w - 1

out = np.zeros((h, w_out), dtype=arr.dtype)

rows = np.arange(h)[:, None]
cols = rows + np.arange(w)

out[rows, cols] = arr
```

---

out:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 3]])
```

---

Intermediates:

```
>>> rows
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
>>> cols
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use the `triu` and `tril` Numpy functions

```
import numpy as np

x=np.array([[1],
       [2 ],
       [3]])
diagonal_length = len(x)
repeats = 2

y = x*np.ones(diagonal_length+(repeats-1))
print("Intermediate step:\n", y)

z = np.tril(np.triu(y,0),repeats-1)
print("\nOutput:\n",z)
```

This first makes a full grid, whose *height* is your diagonal length, and whose *width* is a bit wider, to accommodate your multiple diagonals.

```
Intermediate step:
 [[1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [2. 2. 2. 2.]
 [3. 3. 3. 3.]]
```

Then it uses `triu` and `tril` to zero out the non-diagonal regions.
In the code above, the length of the diagonal is automatically calculated from your input, and you can manually set how many repeats you want.

```
Output:
 [[1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 2. 2. 0.]
 [0. 0. 3. 3.]]
```

Comment: What if it's not a repeating 1d array?

Comment: and the 2d array can be of any size?